# Laravel 5.4 change password crypting method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How can I change the password crypting algorithm for the auth in Laravel.
I see that in the register controller there is this function:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

and I can change the bcrypt function here but how to make the login check the password with my custom hashing algorithm that I will make?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own `HashServiceProvider` (its a service provider) so use artisan to create your own (you may call it same as original)

```
$ artisan make:provider HashServiceProvider
```

Now copy most of the body of stock HashServiceProvider (the stock one can be found in [\Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Hashing/HashServiceProvider.php#L7-L36)) and fix namespaces and imports. Now go to **config/app.php** and find HashServiceProvider and change stock HashServiceProvider for your own service provider, given that you did exactly as I guided you should notice no change what so ever.

Now you have to create (implement) your own hashing functions. You have two options:

A. extend the original BcryptHasher

```
<?php
namespace Your\Namespaced\Hasher;
use Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher as OriginalHasher;
class BcryptHasher extends OriginalHasher
{...} // and change what you need
```

example of this method can be found in [Kyslik/django-bcrypt](https://github.com/Kyslik/django-bcrypt) repository

B. create new class and implement [Hasher interface](https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/blob/5.4/Hashing/Hasher.php)

```
<?php
namespace Your\Namespaced\Hasher;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher;
class MyHasher implements Hasher {...} // IDE should scream at you with methods you need to implement
```

Finally in your service provider (HashServiceProvider) change `register()` method to return your implementation of hashing.

Do a `$ composer dump-autoload` and you may enjoy your own shiny hashing.